# Cognos 10: Rendering Performance IE vs Firefox and Chrome

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I've been dealing with a particularly slow running page which I've been attributing to issues with the queries. In IE 9 or 11 (with compatability view settings enabled) the report consistently runs for over 1 minute without completing.

I've tested the same page in Firefox and Chrome and found it runs in 15-20 seconds in it's worst case scenario (i.e. the most complicated set of prompts being used).

Has anyone encountered anything like this or do you have any ideas about what may be causing the problem in IE?

Comment: It's all about JavaScript.  I've seen the exact behavior before in dashboards (Cognos Workspace or whatever they call it now), Chrome tends to be fastest.  I don't remember if clearing the compatibility  settings helped or not, but Chrome consistently beat IE in our testing.

Comment: Are you sure it's not caching (Both Cognos and browser)?
Try to run the report fist in FF and then in IE, Try to run report in private mode on both browsers, see if it makes difference.
Also, under report properties, in Report tab->Advanced options, try to uncehck the Enable selection-based interactivity in HTML reports option. See if it makes any change in the performance.